# How to pass editable table row value another function

Tags: javascript

**onchange to pass Item_No in do_sum() function.**
when i change my_txt_bx colume then call do_sum function and pass row number or
Item_No.

```
var my_txt_bx ='shipped_qty" onchange="do_sum(Item_No);"';  
$('#myTableEdit').Tabledit({
            editButton: true,
            removeButton: false,
            columns: {
             identifier: [0, 'Item_No'],
             editable: [[0, 'Item_No'],[1, 'Item'],[2, 'Units'],[3, 'Required'],[4, 'Approved'],[5,my_txt_bx],[6,'Total']]                    
  }
});
function do_sum(Item_No)
{
    alert('Item_No..'+Item_No)
}
```

Comment: row value don't pass.how can i solve it?